# Split C string after identifier

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

Quick question: I want to split a string literal (a file path) at the last "/".

So, from this: `"/folder/new/new2/new3"`
to this as the result: `"/folder/new/new2"`

So basically, I always want the result to be one directory behind the absolute path provided.

I've been using `strtok` something akin to this to get the last directory, but I don't know an easy way to get the *second to last* directory. :

```
    char *last
    char *tok = strtok(dirPath, "/");
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
         last=tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have not. I just looked it up and this could work perfectly. I could get the index of the last "/" and then split the string there. I'm new to C so some of these functions are new to me. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ is a good resource. It is a C++ website, but it has good documentation for C libraries.

Comment: Answer provided below, accounting for trailing slashes in path name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reference to user3121023 's suggestion I used `strrchr` and then placed a null-terminator in place of the last occurring "/".

```
char str[] = "/folder/cat/hat/mat/ran/fan";
char * pch;
pch=strrchr(str,'/');
printf ("Last occurence of '/' found at %d \n",pch-str+1);
str[pch-str] = '\0';
printf("%s",str);
```

This worked perfectly, the result printed is "/folder/cat/hat/mat/ran".

Comment: This fails if the path has a trailing slash. Depending on the scenario, two trailing slashes (ie: symlink directory traversal) is a valid scenario.

Comment: I'm using this for a Virtual FAT file system that I'm creating. There won't be any trailing slashes. Valid point though for general application.

Comment: Depending on how your path string generation is done, it may still be possible to have a single trailing slash in any case. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file

Answer (score 0):

Wow am I rusty on straight C, but here goes. A loop similar to your existing code finds the location of the last slash, by using strstr instead of strtok. From there it's just a matter of copying the portion of the string up to that slash. You could also change dirPath in place by overwriting the last slash with a null terminator, but that could lead to memory leaks (?) depending what else your code does...

```
// find last slash
char *position = strstr(dirPath, "/");
while (strstr(position, "/") != NULL)
{
    position = strstr(position, "/");
}

// now "position" points at the last slash character
if(position) {
    char *answer = malloc(position - dirPath); // difference in POINTERS
    strncpy(answer, dirPath, position - dirPath);
    answer[position - dirPath] = `\0`; // null-terminate the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not compiled and run that. Just for fun.

```
char* p = dirPath, *last = NULL;
for(; *p; p++)
{
   if (*p == '/')
      last = p;
}

if (last)
{
    *last = 0;
    puts(dirPath);
}
```